# when i try to run this it says TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

```
import sys
def main():
    print("\t\tGame Menu\n")
    print("\t\tA - enter your name\n\t\tB - play the game\n\t\tC - quit")
    s = input("please enter your choice").upper()
    valid_option = ['A','B','C']
    while True:
        if s in valid_option['A']:#here
            n=input("please enter your name")
            print("I welcome thee valient night sir", n)
            print("\t\tGame Menu\n")
            print("\t\tA - enter your name\n\t\tB - play the game\n\t\tC - 
            quit")

        elif s in valid_option['B']:#here
            print("the game is starting,")
            print("\t\tGame Menu\n")
            print("\t\tA - enter your name\n\t\tB - play the game\n\t\tC - 
            quit")

        elif s in valid_option['C']:#and here 
            print("you have chosen to depart from our company, farewell 
            traveler")
            sys.exit()
main()
```

when i try to run this it says TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
please help

Comment: What do your think that line of code should do?

Comment: You index lists with numbers, as the error says. What do you expect it to do with the 'B'? Did you mean 1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to achieve with this line:

```
if s in valid_option['A']:#here
```

Perhaps this one will work better for you:

```
if s == 'A':
```

Answer (score 0):

`valid_option` is a `list`. To lookup values in a list, you must use index notation.

`valid_option[0]` would equal `'A'`, `valid_option[1]` would equal `'B'` and `valid_option[2]` would equal `'C'`.

If you want to look up values using `str` type, your `valid_option` variable needs to be a *dictionary* (i.e. `{}` instead of `[]`), not a list.